# Designing stripe card input widget

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am using stripe for my payment getaway in my android app and I just wanted to know how can I change the design of the card input widget because its so basic, and everything is just position horizontally [image]. Does anyone know how I can fix the design aspect of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can [customize](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/basic#customize-ui) the prebuilt UI's theme, or you can build your own UI and [call the underlying API methods](https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/stripe/com.stripe.android/-stripe/index.html).